# I have got trouble to send id from view to controler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@model IEnumerable<Evidencija.Models.Vozilo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PokreniIzvjestaj";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>PokreniIzvjestaj</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Vozilo</legend>

        <p>

    @Html.DropDownList("Vozila", Model.Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.VoziloID.ToString(), Value = p.VoziloID.ToString() }), "Izaberi vozilo")

        </p>

         <input type="submit" value="Dodaj stavku" />

    </fieldset>
}
```

I want to send id of table vozilo to controler with dropdownlist.
Controler accepts vozilo as a parameter but it is ollways zero.
How can I solve this without using viewmodel.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PokreniIzvjestaj(Vozilo v)
    {
        ReportClass rpt = new ReportClass();
        rpt.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Vozilo.rpt");
        rpt.Load();

        //ReportMethods.SetDBLogonForReport(rpt);

        //ReportMethods.SetDBLogonForSubreports(rpt);

       // rpt.VerifyDatabase();

        rpt.SetParameterValue("@VoziloId",v.VoziloID);

        Stream stream = null;

        stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
         return File(stream, "application/pdf",  "Vozilo.pdf");
        //PortableDocFormat--pdf format
        //application/pdf -- vezan za pdf format, ako je drugi tip mjenja se u zavisnosti od izabranog
        //naziv.pdf -- naziv dokumenta i izabrana ekstenzija

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PokreniIzvjestaj()
    {
        var vozila = db.Voziloes.ToList();
        return View(vozila);
    }
```

There are two method from controler.

Comment: can you show action of controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently binding your drop down to a property named `Vozilo`. A `<select>` post back single value (in your case the `VoziloID` or the selected option. Your POST method then tries to bind a complex object `Vozilo` to an `int` (assuming `VoziloID is typeof`int`) which of course fails and the model is`null`. You could solve this changing the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PokreniIzvjestaj(int Vozilo)
```

The parameter `Vozilo` will now contain the value of the selected `VoziloID`.

However it not clear why you want to *"solve this without using viewmodel"* when using a view model **is** the correct approach

View model

```
public class VoziloVM
{
  [Display(Name = "Vozilo")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Vozilo")]
  public int? SelectedVozilo { get; set; }
  public SelectList VoziloList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult PokreniIzvjestaj()
{
  var viziloList = db.Voziloes.Select(v => v.VoziloID);
  VoziloVM model = new VoziloVM();
  model.VoziloList = new SelectList(viziloList)
  model.SelectedVozilo = // set a value here if you want a specific option selected
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PokreniIzvjestaj(VoziloVM model)
{
  // model.SelectedVozilo contains the value of the selected option
  ....
}
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.VoziloVM>
....
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedVozilo)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedVozilo, Model.VoziloList, "-Please select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedVozilo)
....
```